# Axios - multiple requests for the same resource

Tags: javascript, promise, vuejs2, axios

I'm creating an app where in one page, I have two components requesting the same http resource. In this case I'm using axios and here's one example:

```
axios.get('/api/shift/type')
        .then(
            (response) => {
                self.shiftTypes = response.data;
                success(response.data)
            },
            (response) => {
                error(response)
            }
        );
```

The issue lies in them requesting it almost at the same time. If Component A makes the request at the same time as Component B, 2 request calls are made and they'll get the same data. Is there a way to check if axios currently has an unresolved promise and return the result to both components once the request is resolved?

Not sure if it helps but the app is being built using the vue framework

Thanks

EDIT: I tried storing the promise in memory but Component B never gets the response

```
getShiftTypes(success, error = this.handleError, force = false) {
    if (this.shiftTypes && !force) {
        return Promise.resolve(this.shiftTypes);
    }

    if (this.getShiftTypesPromise instanceof Promise && !force) { return this.getShiftTypesPromise; }

    let self = this;
    this.getShiftTypesPromise = axios.get('/api/shift/type')
        .then(
            (response) => {
                self.shiftTypes = response.data;
                self.getShiftTypesPromise = null;
                success(response.data)
            },
            (response) => {
                error(response)
            }
        );
    return this.getShiftTypesPromise;
}
```

Comment: I guess you need to create some util script for such cases which checks current state of axios promise to the specific url and returns it instead of creating new.

Comment: @Vadim I've updated the question with the full function - I currently have a "service" class that has getShiftTypes() as a function and each component calls that function - I am currently storing the promise in memory but component B gets no data after the promise is resolved

Answer (score 3):

Consider using a cache:

```
let types = { lastFetchedMs: 0, data: [] }

async function getTypes() {

  const now = Date.now();

  // If the cache is more than 10 seconds old
  if(types.lastFetchedMs <= now - 10000) {
    types.lastFetchedMs = now;
    types.data = await axios.get('/api/shift/type');
  }

  return types.data;
}

while(types.data.length === 0) {
  await getTypes();
}
```

Comment: I tried something similar which I'll post in the question but Component B's success promise didn't kick in. Let me know if it's a user error.

Comment: Hmm, actually I dunno if you can do `.then()` multiple times. Maybe a better solution would be to cache the response. Have an object "types" that looks like:

`let types = { timestamp: 1234567, types: []}`

Comment: I edited my answer with something I think will work :-).

Comment: Doesn't look like a clean way of doing it but I'll give it a go

Comment: Haven't had the chance to test it out. Might give it a go next weekend or so.